# Changing variable Key values in Array with a Foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
foreach( $notZeroValue as $cardSetPosition => $timesChosen){
    echo $groupValue;
    $notZeroValue[$cardSetPosition + ($groupValue*100)] = $notZeroValue[$cardSetPosition];
    unset ($notZeroValue[$cardSetPosition]);
}
```

Output is `0000` (correct because the `$notZeroValue` has four elements and for each one `$groupValue = 0`)

I know there must be a newbie error because changing `*100` to `+100` produces key values `101`, `102`, `103`, `104`.

```
print_r($notZeroValue); //output = array()
```

Comment: So what is the question or problem you're having?

Comment: I think you have to provide more information. Where is `$groupValue` defined? What does the array look like? What is the result you get and what is the result you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `$groupValue` equal to `0` you are getting correct results because

```
$notZeroValue[$cardSetPosition + ($groupValue*100)] = $notZeroValue[$cardSetPosition];
```

becomes

```
$notZeroValue[$cardSetPosition] = $notZeroValue[$cardSetPosition];
```

which is overwriting the array value with itself.

Next you delete the element from array.

So at the end the array will be empty.

But when you change `*` to `+` and `$groupValue` still at `0`:

```
$notZeroValue[$cardSetPosition + ($groupValue+100)] = $notZeroValue[$cardSetPosition];
```

you'll not be overwriting the array values, instead you'll be creating new key/value pairs where keys are 100 more than old keys. Next you delete the old key/value from the array. So at the end you've 4 new key/value pairs.

Comment: Ah! I hadn't realised that! Ok I'll add an if for when $groupValue == 0 THANKS!!